# Ascertaining which widget triggered an EVT_MOUSE_ENTER in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, mouseevent

Is there any way of finding out which widget triggered an EVT_MOUSE_ENTER event or an EVT_MOUSE_LEAVE event? I've got 42 widgets arranged in a 6*7 gridsizer, and I want them each to respond to these two events in the same way. Unfortunately I've looked in the documents and it appears that only button-click events can be traced back to their source using things like event.GetId(). Am I right about this? It will save me a huge amount of code If someone can show that I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it works for me on Windows at any rate:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        btnOne = wx.Button(panel, label="Button One", name="btnOne")
        btnOne.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onEnter)
        btnTwo = wx.Button(panel, label="Button Two", name="btnTwo")
        btnTwo.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onEnter)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btnOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btnTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onEnter(self, event):
        """"""
        widget = event.GetEventObject()
        print widget.GetName()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The idea is to bind the widgets to the same handler, then use GetEventObject() to determine which widget called said handler. Then you can use the widget's own introspection to figure out which one it is via GetId() or GetName(). For more information, check out this tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/

Comment: Thanks Mike, that does work. I do understand the theory I think, but I was just thrown by the fact that neither the wxPython docs that I was using, nor the Wing text-compeletion hints offered these as options for the mouse events.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes you have to load the wxPython demo and watch the events there or you could use the Widget Inspection Tool (http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool) to show events in your own application.